# Open scene graph Delta3d compile error

Tags: c++, opengl, ubuntu-10.04, openscenegraph

I am trying to build the delta3d library, however I am not able to link the complied tests delta3d provides. Here is the error I am getting:

libdtAnim.so: undefined reference to `osg::Uniform::getNameID(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

This occurs in the linking CXX executable ../tests/alltests stage.

The only related post I was able to find has something to do with the c++ compiler not recognizing new standards. I have updated from gcc 4.4 and g++ 4.4 to 4.6 on ubuntu 10.04. Any additional information on how to fix the error would be great. I have stepped into the open scene graph source and have found that there is a osg::Uniform::getNameID(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&); function.

Comment: Looks like the linker cannout find a library. Perhaps you're missing -losg or -losgTerrain or -losgEarth. Have you looked at dependencies required to build delta3d (http://www.delta3d.org/article.php?story=20060220200914706&topic=tutorials) ?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have double check to make sure I am using the correct dependencies that are packaged for the current delta3d developer release. I made sure that osg has installed correctly and can access all osg tests. I will take a look into delta3d's provided make file to see if there is a missing link to a library.